# How to properly render Component after this.setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ResourceForField extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            resources: [],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // get the resources from the Link props and save it into the state
        this.setState({
            resources: this.props.location.resources,
        });
    }

    // This component gets the id of current learningField from the url
    // and the rest(like the resources) from the Link component
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.resources.map(res => (
                    <div>test</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It gets the resources from the Link component, and that works fine. If I check out the state of the Component from the dev tools, the state looks right. And I thought with my logic this should work. So firstly, the state is empty, the component gets rendered, since the state is empty it doesn't render any components. Then, setState gets called, it gets all the resources and saves them into the state, and then the component would re-render, and it should work, but it doesn't. I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error. What is the correct way to do this and how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that `this.props.location.resources` is an array?

Comment: @JonasWilms https://i.imgur.com/7Yyzp73.png completely positive, yes

Comment: Can you show us what the state looks like after componentDidMount

Comment: @Kevin.a `return (<div>{console.log(this.state.resources)}</div>);` gives me this in the console: https://i.imgur.com/bCmZ7j2.png

Comment: {this.state.resources && this.state.resources.map(res => (
                    <div>test</div>
                ))}

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ResourceForField extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            resources: this.props && this.props.location && this.props.location.resources?this.props.location.resources:[],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {

    }

    // This component gets the id of current learningField from the url
    // and the rest(like the resources) from the Link component
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.resources.map(res => (
                    <div>test</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Or use directly props

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ResourceForField extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

    }

    // This component gets the id of current learningField from the url
    // and the rest(like the resources) from the Link component
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { 
                  this.props && this.props.location && 
                  this.props.location.resources
                    ?this.props.location.resources.map(res => (
                    <div>test</div>
               ))
             :null
              }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Or use `componentWillReceiveProps` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`  life cycle methods.
Check `this.props.location.resources` is `array`.
See more: https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607

Comment: It's not good practise to set initial state depending in outside value

Comment: I agree with you, also i mentioned at the end what is the best opinion for my consideration and i saw your solution has a problem.  When props are changed ,state will not change, since componentDidMount doesn't handle props are changed. 
Good aproach use  componentWillReceiveProps or getDerivedStateFromProps life cycle methods, also check props are not null

Comment: I agree,  but I would jut use hooks - useEffect

Answer (score 0):

For first check is `this.props.location.resources` array, or if data type changes you can add checking, you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isArray) `isArray` or with js like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

    export default class ResourceForField extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                resources: [],
            };
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            // get the resources from the Link props and save it into the state
            Array.isArray(this.props.location.resources) {
              this.setState({
                  resources: this.props.location.resources,
              });
            }
        }

        // This component gets the id of current learningField from the url
        // and the rest(like the resources) from the Link component
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.state.resources.map(res => (
                        <div>test</div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Or you can just use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from "react";

export default function ResourceForField({location}) {
  const [ resources, setResources ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location && Array.isArray(location.resources)) {
      setResources(location.resources)
    }
  }, [location]);

    return (
      <div>
        {resources.map(res => (
          <div>test</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's not good practise directly map data and render,  first check data is not null and loaded then render view

Comment: @NijatAliyev why? if your state initially empty array, map will not render anything, and if you will check before setState you will not have any issues, what kind of issues you can have if will not check data is not null before render in our situation?

Answer (score 0):

If the internal state of `ResourceForField` doesn't change and always equals to its prop, you shouldn't save the prop in the state. You can instead create a pure functional component.

Also note that there's nothing preventing you from initializing the state from the props in constructor method. i.e. you're not required to wait for the component to mount in order to access the props.

So, I'd write the following component for `ResourceForField`:

```
function ResourceForField({resources = []}) {
    return (
        <div>
        {
            resources.map(res => (<div>test</div>))
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```